# An object is travelling in a straight line. Its distance, s meters, from a fixed point at time t seconds is given by the expression

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms

$$s=t^3−t^2−6t$$

a) Find ds/dt when t=3 and interpret this result.

b) Find d^2s/dt^2 when t=3 and interpret this result.

c) Find the time in seconds when the velocity is 2m/s

(d) Using the results from 5(c) find the distance travelled when the velocity is 2m/s

A) $$S=t^3-t^2-6t$$
$$dy/dx = 3t^2-2t-6$$
$$When t = 3 = ds/df = 27-6-6 = 15ms^{-1}$$

B)

$$d^2s/dt^2 = 6t -2$$
$$=6(3)-2$$
$$=16$$

If i'm honest i don't know how to progress across the other questions from here. Can some show me how to do it/answer it? Really don't understand it

Comment: Please be more careful with notation.  $s \neq S$.  Then you are taking $\frac {ds}{dt},$ not $\frac {dy}{dx}$.  Then When $t=3$, you should have a comma, not an equals sign, and it is $ds/dt$

Comment: @John: Why not to start accepting some answers? That's the point of this website.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
s=t^3-t^2-6t
$$
then
\begin{align}
\quad\left.\frac{ds}{dt}\right|_{t=3}&=3t^2-2t-6\qquad;\qquad\text{plug in}\ t=3\\
&=3(3)^2-2(3)-6\\
&=\cdots\\
\\
\quad\left.\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\right|_{t=3}&=6t-2\qquad;\qquad\text{plug in}\ t=3\\
&=6(3)-2\\
&=\cdots\\
\\
\frac{ds}{dt}&=2\\
3t^2-2t-6&=2\\
3t^2-2t-8&=0\\
(t-2)(3t+4)&=0\\
t=2\quad&;\quad t=-\frac43\\
\\
s&=t^3-t^2-6t\qquad;\qquad\text{plug in}\ t=2\\
&=(2)^3-(2)^2-6(2)\\
&=\cdots
\end{align}
Interpret it the results by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i just can't get my head round it. I'll just leave it :)

Comment: @John Another hint: During $t=0$ and $t=3$ the object is accelerated but it is travelling to the left side.

Comment: My level of maths skill just isn't high enough for this, i really don't understand. Many thanks anyway :)

Comment: would i not use d^2s/dt^2 and end up with 10meters?

Comment: @John How come you end up with 10 m?

Answer (score 1):

When you differentiate S w.r.t time, this would give you velocity at any time, you derive ds/dt, which is essentially distance and time divided to give speed. Equate the equation with 2, since the velocity at that moment is 2.

You will get a quadratic in t, which can then be solved to get the time. Now that you have the time, you can simply substitute it in the equation to get the displacement by that time :)

All the best

Comment: Also remember that the negative value you obtain is an impossibility thus it should be ignored :)

Comment: how do i answer it if i ignore -8?

Comment: There are always two answers to a quadratic equation if discriminant > 0, which is true in this case, atleast so when i did the math

Comment: For some reason i just can't understand the process. I thank you for your help but i give up :P

Comment: Haha, never give up, once you get the basics you'll see the beauty behind differentiation :P See, the formula for velocity is basically distance/time. When you do the same for its change, you will get instantaneous velocity wouldn't you? :)
so you can differentate the equation wrt time to get teh velocity. Now if you equate the same with 2, it signifies that velocity at that time would be equal to 2, now when you solve it you get the time. Knowledge of quadratics is essential in this question